# Time difference from anywhere in the world

Tags: c#, .net

On my website i want to ensure if the time gap is under 1 minute of `DateTime st` of the below function, an action can be taken otherwise it would be declined. Here's the code for that

```
        DateTime st = MyDate.Value; // current value from database: 2019-12-05 13:20:15.478
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan span = now.Subtract(st);
        int expMin = 1;

        if (span.Minutes < expMin)
        {
            // Do something
        }
        else
        {
            // Ignore
        }
```

So based on the above date value the service cant be accessed after **2019-12-05 13:21:15.478**

This works locally and on my server but I've seen some reports where some users are accessing the service from another country. Is there another way i should be ensuring the time, no matter which country the user is from, can't be accessed after the one minute timespan?

Comment: you will need to consider using GST timezones (meaning save and retrieve GST in database for this column) for these kind of scenarios.

Comment: Always store UTC (coordinated universal time) times in your database.  Then you can easily compare that to `DateTime.UtcNow`

Comment: @BrianRogers Correct. I meant UTC not GST.

Comment: You will lose the information of the local time if you use UTC. If you don't need this information it would be the easiest solution.

Comment: The time stored on the dB is using DateTime.Now() so do I need to convert it to UTC first?

Comment: @BrianRogers: Not *always* - see https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/. Often it's the right thing to do, but not always.

Comment: @Computer: If this is intended to be a timestamp effectively, then using `DateTime.UtcNow` would be a good idea, yes.

Comment: the time stored on db needs to be UTC (using DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() or DateTime.UtcNow)

Comment: Right, looks like I've made some bad decisions here.... Jon Skeet So this is a timestamp of accessing the system, then having one minute after which the user is locked out. @sam how would I deal with the existing time stored on the database (perhaps convert it first??)

Comment: "Convert data in existing column" depends upon usages of that column in your application. If you are using this column multiple places, then you will end-up modifying all those touch points to address this issue. In this case, adding new column which holds converted UTC date is better option. If there are not many touch points in application, then yes, you can convert the existing column first. if you are using SQL Server 2016 , then it has in-built function AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' which makes your life easier with conversion process of existing data.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use DateTimeOffset to consider the timezone of your users.

I assume that "MyDate" is passed by the client. See the following example.

```
        var myDate = new DateTimeOffset(2019, 12, 05, 13, 20, 15, 478, new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0, 0, 0));
        var now = new DateTimeOffset(2019, 12, 05, 14, 20, 45, 478, new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0, 0, 0));

        var span = now.Subtract(myDate);
        int expMin = 1;

        if (span.Minutes < expMin)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do something");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ignore");
        }
```